# How to get an OpenStreetMap image in adobe air?

Tags: air, openstreetmap

I try to load an image from openstreetmap into an air application using javascript and html but the image doesnt appear. I've no problems getting images from flickr. This is the image url: [Map image from OSM](http://dev.openstreetmap.org/~pafciu17/?module=map&bbox=13.36430781,52.51927119,13.365212190000001,52.51836681&width=1080&height=600)

Comment: Without any hints of your code I'm afraid we can't help you. Please provide more details about your code.

Comment: There isnt much code. First I thought it was an javascript error but when I simply have an img tag with he above url as src no image will be diplayed but the "image not found" icon. Maybe its because there is no .png in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the missing file extension is the problem, try another source for OpenStreetMap graphics.
The export tab may help you:

The following url will export you a map for the given coordinates:

http://tile.openstreetmap.org/cgi-bin/export?bbox=7.3229,51.4641,7.6127,51.6127&scale=110000&format=png

Lat = 51.4641 - 51.6127
Lon = 7.3229 - 7.6127
Format = mapnik
File format = png
Scale = 110000

This URL will cause a download but if I tried this:

```
<img src="http://tile.openstreetmap.org/cgi-bin/export?bbox=7.3229,51.4641,7.6127,51.6127&scale=110000&format=png" alt="OSM-Map" width="100%" />
```

And it worked, the map was displayed.
Maybe this is a simple solution to your problem